# How to use 'or' condition or 'is defined ' to pass environment variable in Ansible template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

My scenario is to pass only one of the variable to an Ansible template file, so in Jinja.

The logic should be: if `variable_a` is passed assign `var_a` and ignore `var_b` else assign `var_b`.

I pass them externally while executing playbook like

```sh
ansible-playbook playbooks/deploy.yaml \
  -e 'variable_a=${variable_a}' \
  -e 'variable_b=${variable_b}'
```

I want to use `or` in a condition while passing the variables in a template.

Here is the Ansible template

```
key = {{ variable_a if variable_a is defined else variable_b }}
```

I have also tried this

```
key = {{ variable_a | default(variable_b) }}
```

My problem with this is `variable_b` is not getting assigned if `variable_a` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out I was missing `True` in

```
key = {{ variable_a | default(variable_b) }}
```

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html).

Final statement is

```
key = {{ variable_a | default(variable_b, True) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
key = "{% if variable_a is defined %}{{ variable_a }}{% else %}{{ variable_b }}{% endif %}"
```

Comment: same behavior , if var_a is defined  gets  assigned , else statement is providing empty variable

Comment: What is the value in variable_b ? Can you attach the job log with debug mode ?